# field extension $K\subset L$ and Uniqueness of $G$ such that $K=L^{G}$

Tags: field-theory

Let $K\subseteq L$ be a algebraic field extension. If there exists subgroups $G_{1},G_{2}\subseteq$ Aut$(L)$ such that $K=L^{G_{1}}=L^{G_{2}}$, does $G_{1}=G_{2}$ holds?

($L^{G}=\{a\in L:\sigma a =a$ for all $\sigma \in G\})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: Take $K=\Bbb F_p$ and $L$ its algebraic closure $\overline {\Bbb F_p}$. Then $\text{Aut}(L)=\hat {\Bbb Z}$. Take $\varphi$ to be the Frobenius automorphism $x\mapsto x^p$, then the subgroup of $\text{Aut}(L)$ generated by $\varphi$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$ and hence not the whole group $\text {Aut}(L)$, but they have the same fixed field $\Bbb F_p$.
However, by the Fundamental Theorem of Galois theory the result is true for finite separable extensions. More generally, if $L$ is an infinite algebraic separable extension, then $G=\text{Aut}(L/K)$ becomes a topological group, where a fundamental system of neighborhoods of $1$ is given by the subgroups $\text{Aut}(L/M)$, where $M$ ranges over all the finite subextension of $K$ in $L$. If we now restrict ourselves to closed subgroups $G_1, G_2\le G$, then again the result is true, as in this case the subextensions correspond one-one to the closed subgroups of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general result, I believe due to Artin, which can be used as a foundation for Galois theory. It says that if $L$ is a field, and $G$ is a *finite* group of automorphisms of $L$, then $L / L^{G}$ is Galois, with Galois group $G$.

So *if your subgroups are finite*, the answer is yes, as
$$
G_{1} = \operatorname{Gal}(L/K) = G_{2}.
$$

*In the infinite-dimensional case, however, the answer is negative*, see for instance [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27119/the-algebraic-closure-of-a-finite-field-and-its-galois-group) (in particular point (iii) there). This has to do with the fact that in the infinite case, to get the one-to-one Galois correspondence you need to restrict yourself to subgroups of the Galois group that are closed in the Krull topology; all subgroups that share the same closure will also share the same set of fixed points.

**PS** The example just posted by @walcher is exactly the same of the post I quoted, indeed possibly the most natural one.