# Galois group of algebraic closure of a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

> Is there any element of finite order of the Galois group of algebraic closure of a finite field, and if there is how can I construct it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2806720/show-that-circ-fr3-circfr2-circ-fr1-in-operatornamegal/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Undoubtedly you are only interested in non-trivial such elements. They do not exist.

Assume that $\sigma$ is such an automorphism of $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$. By replacing $\sigma$ with its appropriate power, we can then assume that its order is a prime number $\ell$. Let $K$ be the fixed field of $\sigma$.

Let $x\in\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$ be such an element that $\sigma(x)\neq x$. Then
$L:=\Bbb{F}_p(x)=\Bbb{F}_{p^r}$ for some integer $r>1$. The restriction of $\sigma$
to $L$ is then a non-trivial automorphism, so the order of $\sigma\vert_L$ is necessarily also $\ell$, and $[L:K\cap L]=\ell$.

Let $m=r\ell, E=\Bbb{F}_{p^m}$. The restriction $\sigma\vert_E$ is non-trivial, because $x\in E$. Therefore also $[E:E\cap K]=\ell$. But $L$ is the only subfield of $E$ such that $[E:L]=\ell$. Therefore the fixed field of $\sigma\vert_E$ should be $L$ contradicting the fact that $\sigma\vert_L$ is non-trivial.

---

The same conclusion follows from the observation that $\hat{\Bbb{Z}}$ has no non-trivial torsion elements.

Comment: Why $[L:K∩L]=l$?

Comment: @Comol If $G$ is a finite group of automorphisms of a field $K$, and $K^G$ is the fixed field, then always $[K:K^G]=|G|$.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something simple but why is $\sigma$ restricted to $L$ an automorphism? That is, I don't see why $\sigma(x) \in L$.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani $L$ is Galois over $\Bbb{F}_p$, so any $\Bbb{F}_p$-automorphism of any field containing $L$ will map $L$ to itself. Alternatively, $L$ is the set of zeros of $x^{p^r}-x$, and $\sigma$ has to map a zero of that polynomial to another zero.

Comment: Compare with extensions of rationals: Any automorphism of any field containing $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ has to map $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ to itself, because it is Galois over $\Bbb{Q}$. On the other hand, an automorphism of a field containing $\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2)$ may map it to one of its conjugate fields $\Bbb{Q}(\omega^k\root3\of2)$.

Comment: Yep, got it. Thanks!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen "By replacing σ with its appropriate power, we can then assume that its order is a prime number ℓ". Why is replacing $\sigma $ with an appropriate power allowed and why do you want order to be a prime number?

Comment: @Avenger. An exercise for you: *If a group has an element of a finite order, then it also has an element such that the order is a prime number.* I wanted a prime because the rest of the argument needs it.

Answer (score 6):

No, there are not. Let $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ be an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$. Then $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}/\mathbb{F}_p$ is an infinite Galois extension (infinite, algebraic, normal, separable) with pro-finite Galois group 
$$
Gal(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}/\mathbb{F}_p)=\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}=\varprojlim \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}.
$$
This is the pro-finite completion of $\mathbb{Z}$. By Artin-Schreier, the torsion subgroup
must be trivial or cyclic of order $2$. It is trivial, so there are no
no non-trivial elements of finite order. 
One could ask the same question for the absolute Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$. Here it is cyclic of order $2$. 
The only element of finite order in the absolute Galois group $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ is, up to conjugation, complex conjugation.

For details on the group $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ see [Elements in $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$, the profinite completion of the integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256732/elements-in-hat-mathbbz-the-profinite-completion-of-the-integers).

Comment: Why do you need Artin-Schreier to conclude that $\widehat{\mathbf Z}$ is torsion-free?...

Comment: I do not need Artin-Schreier for that, but it is a result which is relevant anyway for such questions (see the other example).

Comment: Even if the only element of finite order in the absolute Galois group $G$ of $\Bbb Q$ is, up to conjugation, complex conjugation, I think that the torsion subgroup of $G$ is infinite (and not cyclic of order $2$ as claimed), since there are many embeddings $\overline{\Bbb Q} \to \Bbb C$.

Comment: Just noticed your comment, @Watson. There is a torsion *subset*, but it is not a *subgroup*. In a nonabelian group, product of two torsion elements need not be torsion.

Comment: @Lubin : thank you for this correction. I was probably confused by the sentence "Here it is cyclic of order $2$." in the answer.