# Galois group for the algebraic closure of a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

> If $N$ is the algebraic closure of a finite field $F$, prove that $\operatorname{Gal}(N/F)$ is an abelian group and that any element of the Galois group has infinite order.

If $N$ were a finite extension of $F$, then it would be easy to see that $\operatorname{Gal}(N/F)$ is a cyclic group. But I don't know if I can proceed using this idea in the above case.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/585962/11619) for lack of elements of finite order. Abelian? How will a commutator act on any finite extension $E$ of $F$? Recall that $N$ is the union of such extensions $E$.

Answer (score 3):

Let F be your finite field, say of order q (where q is necessarily a power of a prime p). It is known from the elementary theory of finite fields that any extension E/F of degree n is Galois, with cyclic Galois group isomorphic to (**Z**/n**Z**, +), generated by the so called Frobenius automorphism, sending x to x^q. "The" algebraic closure of F being the inductive limit of the finite extensions of F, its Galois group over F is the projective limit of the **Z**/n**Z**, usually denoted **Z**^, the "profinite completion" of **Z**. By construction (check on projective limits, or just argue that **Z** is dense in **Z**^ with respect to the profinite topology), **Z**^ is abelian and has no non null element of finite order.