# What do we know about fields possessing an involution?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, involutions

The field $\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers has an involution, and the same is true of the field of algebraic numbers (the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$) and of the field of complex ruler-and-compass constructible complex numbers; in all three cases the involution is the complex conjugation. Any quadratic extension of a field $F$ has an involution that fixes every element of $F$.

**Question.** $~$If $F$ is a field of characteristic different from $2$ whose every element is a square, does it follow that it has an involution? In particular, does every algebraically closed field of characteristic not $2$ have an involution?

I suspect that the answers are NO and NO$\ldots$ but do not really know, of course, otherwise I would not be asking.

Are there any theorems that say if a field is such and such, then it has an involution, or, perhaps, that under certain conditions there are *no* involutions? That is, are there theorems that supply fields with involutions (which are not among the examples given above), or fields without an involution? I would appreciate any hints or references. I hit on this question during my current work; it created quite a crater which I want to somehow fill in.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding? Doesn't *every* field have involutions? For example, $x\mapsto -x$? And of course $x\mapsto x$?

Comment: An involution is an automorphism of order $2$. The map $x\mapsto-x$ is an automorphism of order $2$ of the underlying additive group of a field (of characteristic not $2$, remember), but is not an automorphism of the field. The identity mapping is an automorphism of order $1$, the only one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A counter-example is given by the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ of a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ of characteristic $p>2$.

Indeed, since any automorphism $\sigma$ of $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ fixes all elements of the prime field $\mathbb{F}_p$, then this $\sigma$ is an element of the [absolute Galois group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_Galois_group) of $\mathbb{F}_p$, which is isomorphic to the inverse limit of all $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and [contains no non-trivial element of finite order](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/585962/110831).  In particular, $\sigma$ cannot be an involution.

I am not aware of conditions guaranteeing the existence of an involution for a given field.

Comment: So this is it for fields of characteristic $p>2$. How about fields of characteristic $0$? The algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ does have an involution.

Comment: @chizhek Good question.  I haven't found a counter-example in characteristic zero.

Comment: An idea. Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $0$ every element of which is a square. There is an $i\in F$ such that $i^2=-1$. Let $E$ be a maximal subfield of $F$ that does not contain $i$. If we can prove that $F=E(i)\ \ldots$

Comment: @chizhek Good point.  According to [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/86395/algebraically-closed-fields-with-proper-maximal-subfields), you can always find such a subfield $E$ if $F$ is algebraically closed.  There still remains the case when $F$ is not algebraically closed...

Comment: The MO question asks for a maximal proper subfield of a field (in this particular question, an algebraically closed one), which may exist or not. But the field $E$ in my previous comment always exists: the union of a nonempty chain of subfields of the field $F$ that exclude $i$ is a subfield excluding $i$. The question here is, is the subfield $E$ "almost at the top", meaning $E(i)=F$.

Comment: Ah, now I see: I said "Let $E$ be a maximal subfield of $F$ that does not contain $i$." This was sloppily formulated. I should say "Let $E$ be a subfield of $F$ maximal in the family of all subfields of $F$ that do not contain $i$." Or perhaps, "$\ldots$ maximal with respect to the property of excluding $i$."

Comment: @chizhek Yes, that is how I understood your comment.  But unless I understand the MO answers wrongly, they state that *any* algebraically closed field of characteristic zero admits a maximal proper subfield, and that this maximal subfield never contains $i$; moreover, adding $i$ yields the whole algebraically closed field.

Comment: Yes, it is so. But the field $F$ in my question (now of characteristic $0$) has the weaker property that every element is a square. Considering maximal $i$-excluding subfields guarantees their existence. I also tried another approach: maximal formally real subfields, which likewise exist. In either case I was able to get a few steps ahead, but then run into a wall.

Comment: The complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ contain uncountably many involutions, exactly one of which is continuous (with the usual metric topology on $\mathbb{C}$) and it has $\mathbb{R}$ as its fixed field. This is one definition of the real numbers, in addition to it being the unique topologically complete, linearly ordered field. (This sort-of spells the continuous involution idea out https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110428/nondegenerate-involutions-on-the-complex-numbers-always-just-conjugation)

Comment: What is the state-of-the-art in characteristic 2? Sorry if this is an ignorant question. I guess every $[\mathbb{F}_{2^r}: \mathbb{F}_{2^{r-1}}] = 2$; what about the existence of involutions of $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_2$?

Comment: I have one more dumb question: $\mathbb{C}$ is not $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ but its metric completion with respect to the usual modulus metric/valuation, $[\overline{\mathbb{Q}}]$; are there involutions on the metric/valuation completions of the various $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$'s with respect to their usual valuations, $[\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p]$, for both $p=2$ and $p>2$? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: (If one could prove any involution on $[\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p]$ would have to send all and only algebraic elements to algebraic elements -- maybe that's obvious? -- then any involution on $[\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p]$ would restrict to an involution on $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$; if every involution on $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ extends to an involution on $[\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p]$ -- again, maybe this is obvious -- then it does so uniquely, so "No involutions on $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$" implies "No involutions on $[\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p]$".)