# Show that $\cdots\circ$ Fr$^{3!}\circ$Fr$^{2!}\circ$ Fr$^{1!} \in\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb F_p}/\mathbb F_p)\setminus\langle$ Fr $\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Let  $\varphi=\cdots\circ \operatorname{Fr}^{3!}\circ \operatorname{Fr}^{2!}\circ \operatorname{Fr}^{1!}$, where $\operatorname{Fr}$ is the Frobenius endomorphism. Show that $\varphi \in \operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb F_p}/\mathbb F_p)\setminus\langle\operatorname{Fr}\rangle$.

First of all, I had to show that $\varphi$ is well-defined. For this argument I proved that for every $\mathbb F_p\subset\mathbb K \subset  \overline{\mathbb F_p}$, if $[\mathbb K:\mathbb F_p]< \infty$, then there exists $N$ such that for every  $n\geq N$, $\operatorname{Fr}^{n!}|_\mathbb K=\operatorname{Id}$. How do I continue from here?

Comment: The exponent means composition too? (So $Fr^2= Fr \circ Fr$ etc.?)

Comment: (A side note: one can see that the absolute Galois group of a finite field is _pro-cyclic_, but not cyclic, for it is uncountable — while any cyclic group is countable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make the following observations, and/or justify the claims:

- $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$ is the union of the fields $\Bbb{K}$ that you have considered. By your result this implies that the infinite composition is actually well defined. Furthermore, it also follows that it is an automorphism of $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$.
- But, the composition $\varphi$ is not in the group generated by $\mathbf{Fr}$. For otherwise we would have $\varphi=\mathbf{Fr}^n$ for some integer $n$. But, if $k$ is a positive integer such that $n\mid k!$ then $n\not\equiv n+k!\pmod{(k+1)!}$. This implies that the restriction of $\varphi$ to either $\Bbb{F}_{p^{k!}}$ or $\Bbb{F}_{p^{(k+1)!}}$ is not equal to $\mathbf{Fr}^n$.

Comment: I'm not happy with the formulation of the last claim. The idea is that the restriction of $\varphi$ to the fields in the tower $$\Bbb{F}_{p^{1!}}\subset \Bbb{F}_{p^{2!}}\subset \Bbb{F}_{p^{3!}}\subset \cdots$$ cannot be a "stable" power of $\mathbf{Fr}$ because it "keeps on changing forever". There is probably a cleaner way of  capturing this idea :-(

Comment: It's equivalent that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k! \in \hat{\Bbb Z} = \lim \Bbb Z/ n \Bbb Z$ is not a natural number, right?

Comment: Never saw that expression before. what is $\hat {\mathbb Z}$?

Comment: The inverse limit of all $\Bbb Z / n\Bbb Z$. It has a ring structure which is sometimes called the Prufer ring, but that is misleading because different things are called Prufer rings as well. In any case, seen as a topological additive group it is isomorphic to $Gal(\overline{\Bbb F_p}|\Bbb F_p)$ (by sending the Frobenius to any topological generator, like 1.)

Comment: Correct, of course @TorstenSchoeneberg. I was hoping to do without the definition of either the Prüfer ring or the inverse limit :-/

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  For the second point, perhaps one could argue as follows: Suppose $\varphi=\mathbf{Fr}^n$ for some $n$. By looking at the restriction of $\varphi$ 
 to $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$, we duduce that $$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}k!\equiv n \mod{m!}$$ for all $m\geq 1$. We also have $\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}k!\leq (m-1)\cdot(m-1)!<m!$, so if $m$ is large enough (that $m!>|n|$), we have $\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}k!=n$ if $n$ is positive, and $\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}k!-m!=n$ if $n$ is negative. In either case $|n|$ must be arbitrarily large, absurd.