# $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$ is not a finite degree extension of any proper subfield.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Consider $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$. I want to see that: for every proper subfield $K \leq \bar{\mathbb{F}_p}$, $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p/K$ is *not* a finite extension.

It is known that, and can be somewhat easily shown that $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p = \cup_{n \geq 1}\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$

Now, if any of the proper subfields have the form $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, it is easy enough to see that $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p \neq \mathbb{F}_{p^n}(\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_m)$ for some $\alpha_i$, by going high up enough, i.e, to some big enough $m$ such that $\alpha_i \not \in \mathbb{F}_{p^m} \subseteq \bar{\mathbb{F}_p}$

The problem is characterizing the proper subfields. Is every subfield of $\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}$ going to have this form? Can we have an infinite intermediate subfield?

Comment: Surely $\cup_{k\geqslant 1}\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$ where $q=p^s$ is proper and not a finite extension.

Comment: Finite extension as in finite degree not finite cardinality. I'm referring to the index of the extension.

Comment: But yes, there are infinite intermediate fields which I have now realized, if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: Remains to be seen their degree however.

Comment: Finite degree extensions of $\mathbb{F}_p$ are finite sets.

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking at if $\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}$ is a finite degree extension of any subfield $K$ or if they are all finite.

Comment: ancient's field is indeed infinite, which is what is asked for in the last sentence of the question.  But is it really proper?

Comment: I think it is proper, if we take some $t$ prime to $s$ for example. But even so, even with infinite intermediate field, is $\bar{\mathbb{F}_p}$ a finite extension of ancient's field? Or is degree still finite.

Comment: Would $\cup_{k\geqslant 1}\mathbb{F}_{q^{2^k}}$ be better?

Comment: My comment only referred to the last question you asked. I am not claiming to have an answer to the first part.

Comment: @ancientmathematician That looks good to me.  The Galois group here is the profinite integers, if $q=p$ this looks like picking out just the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ factor.

Comment: The fields you're discussing are not proper. Any finite field of characteristic $p$ has the same algebraic closure.

Comment: @Mentos So what? No one has said my example is the algebraic closure of anything.

Comment: Your first example is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_q$, hence equal to $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$. I misread the second as $q^{2k}$, I agree with the last example

Comment: @Mentos Thanks.

Comment: Correct. $\bigcup_{k\ge1}\Bbb{F}_{q^{2^k}}$ (with the union taken inside a fixed algebraic closure $\overline{\Bbb{F}_q}$) is infinite. But it is, of course, a long way from $\overline{\Bbb{F}_q}$. It only consists of the zeros of irreducible polynomials $\in\Bbb{F}_q[x]$ of degree that is a power of two. A "complementary" example would consist of the zeros of all odd degree irreducible polynomials $\in\Bbb{F}_q[x]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Slade explained (+1) this follows either from the known structure of the automorphism group of $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$ or from a theorem of Artin & Schreier stating that any finite extension $\overline{K}/K$, with the bigger field algebraically closed, is of the form $\overline{K}=K(\sqrt{-1})$.

An elementary argument can also be given. Assume that $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}/K$ is a finite extension. Then that extension is Galois. It is obviously normal, and it is also separable because every element of $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$ belongs to a finite field, and hence is a zero of a separable polynomial over the prime field (and hence also over $K$). By basic Galois theory this implies that $\overline{\Bbb{F}_p}$ has an automorphism of a finite order. But I shamelessly link to [an old elementary answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/586109/11619) explaining that there are no such automorphisms.

Comment: Very nice! I was hoping for a more elementary proof!

Comment: @CruiseControl If you get a chance to study Galois theory of infinite algebraic extensions, you will learn that there is a topology on the Galois group $G$ such that the intermediate fields correspond bijectively with the *closed* subgroups of $G$. That gives you a better description of the intermediate fields in terms of the closed subgroups of $\hat{\Bbb{Z}}$.

Answer (score 4):

The Galois group here is isomorphic to $G=\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$, the profinite integers.  Since $G$ is torsion-free, there are no finite index subfields.

This also follow from Artin-Schreier, though I don't know offhand of an extremely clean and short proof in the case of finite fields.